# WebSocket not running on live domain node server while live server running .but running on localhost node server. Please need to solve

Tags: node.js, sockets, web-services, websocket, node-modules

(index):116 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
at HTMLFormElement. (http://apppanel.fitnfurious.in/chatm/m/:116:8)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDPVr.png)

Comment: This error describes that you're trying to send data over a webSocket connection BEFORE it has finished connecting.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to send data with a websocket that hasn't connected yet. Fix that.